# Dynamics AX 2012 Formdatasource::executeQuery calls a lot more methods on specific remote servers

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

All the AX clients are accessed through RDS.

We received a ticket a few weeks ago that a certain application had bad performance. We were looking in to it but could not reproduce the problem. After some testing around, it seemed that the problem only occurs on 2 specific remote desktops, and not on the others.

Then we started tracing the application on both servers with the Tracing cockpit and I noticed that on the slow-server, the executeQuery calls a lot more of the same methods as the fast-server, in particular, SysQueryRun::next and QueryBuildDataSource::findRange

So I decided to setup a very simple testform with the same basic logic as the application with issues, and this seems reproducible, albeit a lot less calls than the actual application.

The logic used on the form is very simple. In the active of the header-formdatasource, we call the detail-formdatasource executeQuery and apply the filters to the detail-table.

On the fast-server:

[Trace-faster-server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i21AE.png)

On the slow-server:

[Trace-slower-server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyfte.png)

What could be the reason this happens? It certainly has an impact.

I tried the following things:

- Googled a lot but no relevant search results, but could be the case that the search keywords are very generic
- Restart AOS, remote desktop servers
- CIL-compile
- Recreated the form to isolate the issue and it does remain

Comment: Verify the AX client is the same version on every server by going `Help>About`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that all servers and clients have the same Kernel builds by going to `Help>About`.

Alternatively, you can check the user log (\Menus\SystemAdministration\Inquiries\Users\User log), and on the general tab it shows the different build #'s for the logins. I typically personalize that form and move it to the grid. That way I can just scroll up/down and look for client mismatches.

Comment: This did fix it. It turns out my Client version matched on all servers but the Kernel version did not. After updating the client on the server, the issue was fixed. Thanks a bunch man!

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar issues happen when the AUC/KTI cache files get corrupted. They're safe to delete and get rebuilt every time a new client is opened.

I wrote a little PowerShell script that you can run on the affected server(s) and it will delete the files for you. It also will do a "simulate" delete so you can see what will be deleted if you want beforehand.

You need to make sure the users are not logged into AX on the server or the delete will fail on some files because they'll be locked. If that happens, it's no big deal...just kick the user(s) out of AX and rerun the script until everything is deleted correctly.

```
Write-Host "For the server $($env:COMPUTERNAME), this script will delete AX user application specific cache files. This is different than 'Usage Data' which will not be affected." -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host "Specifically it removes *.AUC/*.KTI files from each user's %LOCALAPPDATA% directory and the files located in '%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Dynamics Ax' for each user." -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host "It will also save a transcript to the desktop." -ForegroundColor Green
while(-not (($choice= (Read-Host "Do you want to continue? (No will simulate, but not delete) [Y/N]")) -match "^[YNyn]{1}$")){ "Y or N ?"}
$DoDelete = ($true, $false)[!($choice -eq 'Y')]

Start-Transcript -Path (Join-Path ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")) "UserCacheDelTranscript.log") -Append

if (!$DoDelete)
{
    Write-Host "Simulating delete..."
}

Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users" -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    $DelPath = "$($_.FullName)\AppData\Local\*"

    if (Test-Path $DelPath) {
        # Remove *.auc/*.kti files
        Get-ChildItem -Include *.auc, *.kti -Path $DelPath | ForEach-Object {
            Write-Output ("Deleting '{0}'" -f $_.FullName)
            if ($DoDelete) {
                Remove-Item $_
            }
        }
    }

    # Remove other misc cache files
    $DelPath = "$($_.FullName)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Dynamics Ax"
    if (Test-Path $DelPath) {
        Get-ChildItem -Path $DelPath | % {
            Write-Output ("Deleting '{0}'" -f $_.FullName)

            if ($DoDelete) {
                Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName -Recurse -Confirm:$false
            }
        }
    }
}

Stop-Transcript
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. This is something we have tried as well but it made no difference, I should have included it in the post. We actually did a fresh install on a fresh server and the issue persists.

Comment: @KHP did you confirm identical AX versions everywhere too via `Help>About`? Alternatively, you can check the user log (`\Menus\SystemAdministration\Inquiries\Users\User log`), and on the general tab it shows the different build #'s for the logins. I typically personalize that form and move it to the grid. That way I can just scroll up/down and look for client mismatches.

Comment: Yes, I did confirm client versions and there is a descrepancy, so now we try to upgrade the client on one of the servers to see if that has a solutions. Thanks for the help mate, those user logs seem semi-useful aswel. I will keep you updated once we patched it all.

Comment: If there's a discrepancy, then it's most certainly the root cause and I've seen similar behavior. It's because they have different kernels so they're literally running different code behind the scenes, typically on the `super()` call that you can't access. Glad I could help! I'll add a new answer with that information so others can more easily find it once you confirm it's the actual solution.

Comment: Haven't gotten around to patching it just yet, but indeed, it all happens in the super() calls, so we are hopeful, thanks dude and will certainly confirm the solution!